# AngularJS not working in IntelliJ

Tags: angularjs, maven, intellij-idea, frontend

When I'm opening my `index.html` manualy in chrome the `{{message}}` is displayed properly ( Everyone come and see how good I look! ).
But when I'm compiling my project in `IntelliJ (maven)` It shows only `{{message}}` tag.

[Fiddle](http://%09%20jsfiddle.net/dq8r196v/249)

Comment: - is script.js is placed in same folder where index.html is placed? 
- Is internet working properly?

Comment: have you also configured angular js in intellij ? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/15.0/using-angularjs.html?origin=old_help#d721369e14 Seems there is an conflict between two versions of angular js

Comment: @RDX i configured it but still nothing

Answer (score 0):

There might be some conflict with the old version the AngularJs plugin you previously had installed.

Doing a File > Invalidate Caches and Restart > Invalidate and Restart did solve the problem for me.

Intellij IDEA had to re-index the whole project, maybe the previously indexed things where using the old AngularJs Plugin scheme ...

More Details here.. [IntelliJ 13.1 angularjs plugin doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553395/intellij-13-1-angularjs-plugin-doesnt-work)